# Android - ViewPager as a Header in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

**TL;DR** - ViewPager as ListView Header creating some issues.

my activity has a ListView that presents several types of data..
I have a HeaderView, a sticky view, and the rest of the data is a "normal" list item.

I am using this Library -> https://github.com/LarsWerkman/QuickReturnListView
for my list view.

In my HeaderView i have a view pager for 2 profile images of my users.

2 problems :

1. scrolling the pager right to the next image doesn't open the image to the full screen width..
   (but if scrolling down in the list view, scrolling back up to the top of the screen "redraw" the header view and then if you scroll the pager again it's fixed!)
2. sometimes the images do not load to my view pager.

you can see that bug in those images, first image is of the state from trying to scroll the pager to the right, and the second image is the bug

[image one](http://cl.ly/image/3q210q3r0n39)

[image two](http://cl.ly/image/1U3p3y1b1y1i)

anyone encountered such a problem before?

I've read in some places that using a view pager inside a list view is not exactly optimal, is there a different way to achieve my goal?

Comment: please, add code otherwise no one could help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had that same problem,
try removing that third party library of the list view,
back in the day i was using that same one and it's really buggy.
use a normal listview instead.

Answer (score 1):

A few months ago i did a similar trick as you want to do. I tried almost all libraries in web about this quick return and all of them has bugs and not suitable for me. Also not suitable for a header which contains a viewpager in.

Later i implemented my own scroll listener. This is not exactly a quick return header pattern but you can add animations in if you have time.

```
listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
         @SuppressLint("NewApi")
         @Override
         public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            int scrollOffset = 0;
            float transitionY;

            if (firstVisibleItem > 0) {
               scrollOffset += headerHeight;
               if (firstVisibleItem > 1) {
                  scrollOffset += (firstVisibleItem - 1) * cellHeight;
               }
            }

            if (listView.getChildCount() > 0) {
               scrollOffset += -listView.getChildAt(0).getTop();
               scrollOffset = -scrollOffset;
            }

            float scrollDelta = scrollOffset - prevOffset;
            float nextY = mQuickReturnView.getY() + scrollDelta;

            if (nextY < minRawY) {
               transitionY = minRawY;
            }
            else if (nextY > qReturnDelta) {
               transitionY = qReturnDelta;
            }
            else {
               transitionY = nextY;
            }

            mQuickReturnView.setY(transitionY);
            prevOffset = scrollOffset;
         }

         @Override
         public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
         }
      });
```

And i used a view pager and a pageradapter in header. In my solution you have to use fixed size for listview items and declare it as **CellHeight** and a fixed size for header. It's **QuickReturnHeight**

It's a bit hard to implement this pattern with ListView + Header + ViewPager.

I hope this'll help you.

Comment: Hi, i can't give fixed size to cells.. it's against my layout design..
tried your solution but it doesn't work for me =\